# Deconvolutional autoencoder in theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I'm new to theano and trying to use the examples [convolutional network](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) and [denoising autoencoder](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html) to make a denoising convolutional network. I am currently struggling with how to make W', the reverse weights. [In this paper](http://people.idsia.ch/~masci/papers/2011_icann.pdf) they use tied weights for W' that are flipped in both dimensions.

I'm currently working on a 1d signal, so my image shape is (batch_size, 1, 1, 1000) and filter/W size is (num_kernels, 1, 1, 10)  for example. The output of the convolution is then (batch_size, num_kernels, 1, 991).
Since I want to W' to be just the flipped in 2 dimensions (or 1d in my case), I'm tempted to do this

```
w_value = numpy_rng.uniform(low=-W_bound, high=W_bound, size=filter_shape)
self.W = theano.shared(np.asarray((w_value), dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
self.W_prime = T.repeat(self.W[:, :, :, ::-1], num_kernels, axis=1)
```

where I reverse flip it in the relevant dimension and repeat those weights so that they are the same dimension as the feature maps from the hidden layer.

With this setup, do I only have to get the gradients for W to update or should W_prime also be a part of the grad computation?

When I do it like this, the MSE drops a lot after the first minibatch and then stops changing. Using cross entropy gives NaN from the first iteration. I don't know if that is related to this issue or if it's one of many other potential bugs I have in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on the validity of your `W_prime` approach but I can say that you only need to compute the gradient of the cost with respect to each of the original shared variables. Your `W_prime` is a symbolic function of `W`, not a shared variable itself so you don't need to compute gradients with respect to `W_prime`.

Whenever you get NaNs, the first thing to try is to reduce the size of the learning rate.

Comment: Ok, then I just need to actually make W' a symbolic function of W. As I understand, repeat does not have a grad operation.

I reduced the learning rate by a few orders of magnitude and you are right, no NaNs now. The cost goes down like this the first few epochs, [800, 44, 34, 30, 27]. The first drop is pretty drastic and I think it might have to do with the data being fairly homogenous, thoughts?

Comment: The line of code you posted originally already makes `W_prime` a symbolic function of `W` (`T.repeat` is a symbolic operation, as is the `[:, :, :, ::-1]` indexing operation). A large initial drop in cost is not necessarily something to worry about but may indicate a poor initialization of your parameters.